# Inline CKEditor adds <br> to empty div on startup

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

CKEditor in Inline mode adds a `<br>` in the source of the document  to an empty `div` when it is initialized. When you check the source in CKEditor it shows completely empty. I guess this is done to stop collapsing the `div` or whatever element it is editing on, but for me this is causing issues since I target the empty div with CSS to display a placeholder.

I have searched about everywhere on how to disable this and have seen some issues with FireFox many years ago, but that seems to be unrelated.

```
<div id="editarea" placeholder="Title"></div>
CKEDITOR.inline('editarea, {});

<style>
  div:empty:after {
    content: attr(placeholder);
  }
</style>
```

When you look in the Developer Tools the source of the document looks like:

```
<div id="editarea" placeholder="Title">
   <br>
</div>
```

Adding the following to the config does not seem to be doing anything:

```
config.fillEmptyBlocks = false;
```

Comment: While it shouldn't cause huge issues maybe this helps ► http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.fillEmptyBlocks

Comment: @Fran, updated the answer, removed the dramatization as well :) FillEmptyBlocks does not work

Answer (score 3):

Can help someone else, the solution I found, pass by the editor event listener:

```
// Ckeditor 4
editor.on('key', function (evt) {
  var selection = editor.getSelection();
  var element = selection.getStartElement();
  var html = element.getHtml();
  var id = element.getId();
  if (evt.data.keyCode !== 13
     && id === 'editarea')) {
     if (html.match(/(&nbsp;)?<br>$/)) {
        element.setHtml('');
     }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

That `<br>` is a "**filler**" and is always placed at input *(editor initialization)* into empty block elements by function [createBogusAndFillerRules](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/major/core/htmldataprocessor.js#L318) to give an height to the element so the user can click on it to edit it.

Actually there is not a CKeditor configuration to avoid this behaviour but, using jQuery, we can remove the `<br>` on `instanceReady.ckeditor` event with:

```
if($(this).html().trim() === '<br>'){
    $(this).html('');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code it is working for me:

For removing br on load

```
$('your_id').ckeditor();    
        CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function() { 
            $('div.application').find('br').remove();   // remove br tag added on empty divs
        });
```

for removing &nbsp use this in destroy function:

```
for(CKname in CKEDITOR.instances) // delete multiple instances of ckeditor
        {
            CKEDITOR.instances[CKname].destroy(function(){
                $("your_id").html(function (i, html) {
                    return html.replace(/&nbsp;/g, ''); // remove &nbsp;
                });
            })
        }
```